# get google map parameters to send as link?

Tags: parameters, google-maps-api-3, hyperlink

built an ok working google map for artist studios. However i want the users to be able to click on a link from the map and goto another page. But when they come back i want the map to be in the position and zoom level as before so they can continue their browsing.

Is there a way to export the current maps position and zoom as a string? The same way you can get a link to a map from maps.google.com? I can then add it to a cookie or hash link.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the center and the zoom as numbers:

```
var centerLat = map.getCenter().lat();
var centerLng = map.getCenter().lng();
var zoom = map.getZoom();
```

Convert these numbers to strings as you like (you can round them first using `toFixed(...)`). Later you parse your strings to get the numbers `centerLat, centerLng, zoom` and set the map position:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(centerLat, centerLng)); 
map.setZoom(zoom);
```

Remark: If you wish a static link to your map, you would construct `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=LAT,LNG&zoom=Z&size=640x340&maptype=roadmap` where `LAT, LNG, Z` are numerical values of `centerLat, centerLng, zoom`, respectively.